# Bootstrap/Flexbox not working as expected. Is there something wrong in my code?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, flexbox

I'm working on a MVC website with a login/signup form and I'm trying to use bootstrap to format the forms. I simply want to center the entire form on the screen but I can only get it centered on the horizontal axis. At this point, only 'justify-content-center' seems to change the layout. I've tried 'align-items-center', 'align-self-center', 'align-content-center', but nothing has changed the look of my page.

Here's my code:

```
<div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
  <div class="login-card">
      <h2 class="page-title">Signup</h2>
      <form class="form signup-form">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="username-signup">Username:</label>
          <input class="form-input" type="text" id="username-signup" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="email-signup">Email:</label>
          <input class="form-input" type="text" id="email-signup" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="password-signup">Password:</label>
          <input class="form-input" type="password" id="password-signup" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">signup</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Not a fix but note that the [<input>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-input-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.

Comment: Please provide more code.  It's impossible to tell what the issue is when you are only showing this little bit.  Please use a snippet and create [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 2):

The default height of the content is the actual rendered height of the content. In order to center content vertically in the viewport, you'll have to make sure that the content has a minimum height of 100% of the viewport.

The appropriate Bootstrap class is `min-vh-100`, which declares `min-height:100vh!important`. Then you can center the content vertically with the class `align-items-center`.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-9ndCyUaIbzAi2FUVXJi0CjmCapSmO7SnpJef0486qhLnuZ2cdeRhO02iuK6FUUVM" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center min-vh-100">
  <div class="login-card">
      <h2 class="page-title">Signup</h2>
      <form class="form signup-form">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="username-signup">Username:</label>
          <input class="form-input" type="text" id="username-signup">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="email-signup">Email:</label>
          <input class="form-input" type="text" id="email-signup">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="password-signup">Password:</label>
          <input class="form-input" type="password" id="password-signup">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">signup</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```